# What should I use to wash the walls in my kitchen prior to repainting them?

Tags: drywall, cleaning, repainting, prepping

I am repainting the walls in my kitchen.   I am sure grease has accumulated.  The instructions say to "wash the walls", but do not say what with.

Should I use vinegar, Clorox, Tide, ...?

Comment: What type of paint is on the walls? Eggshell? Satin? Semi-Gloss? If you have a glossier finish, I would consider a light sanding to rough it up to get better adhesion, this would actually eliminate the need for soap as the grease would get mostly get removed.  You could then just wipe down the walls with a damp cloth

Answer (score 2):

I would use a grout sponge that has a course side.  What you use depends on how dirty the walls are and can range from soap to bleach.  There isn't a perfect solution because soap is fine in most cases (dawn or something similar).

Comment: Bleach disinfects but doesn't cut grease. A grease cutting soap, followed by a clean rinse should do it.

Answer (score 2):

If the sheetrock has paint on it already I would use TSP (trisodium phosphate) it is a general purpose cleaner available in hardware stores. Use the grout sponge as @DMoore suggested, rinse frequently.

Comment: TSP is the US equivalent to sugar soap http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_soap

Answer (score 1):

All painters I've spoken to always use [sugar soap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_soap) to wash walls before repainting.

(This might be a regional thing, though? I'm in Australia...)

Comment: sugar soap is really good for removing grease

Comment: First I've heard of sugar soap.  Interesting.